# rushed to us / rushed over to us

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between

> rushed to us
>
> rushed over to us?

As I understand it, it's the same as "hurried towards us", but I don't understand the meaning of the word "over" in this context. Could you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb "rush" by itself conveys a sense of speed and hurry, but not so much of *motion* and not at all of *direction*. To add the sense of motion and direction, *rush* (and many other verbs) are often coupled with prepositions like *over*, *up*, *in*, etc. Various prepositions add different flavors of motion to the meaning. *Over* refers to a balanced kind of motion where the origin and destination have equal standing (neither is higher or lower, more "inside" or "outside," etc.) than the other.

This use of prepositions together with verbs is very common in English, and in this particular case the sentence would probably sound awkward without some kind of preposition: the bare "rushed to us" is not idiomatic.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: please show some courtesy to Type1A by explaining why you disagree with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to treat **rush over** as a compound verb. You won't find a definition of **rush over** in any dictionary, but if you look for **come over**, you will be able to understand how **over** is used with other verbs of movement. here is the entry from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-over):

> to come to a place, move from one place to another, or move towards someone